# Issue in Xcode 14.2 login option not show when trying to login from account section

Tags: xcode

[image]

I am trying to log in to my Apple account but cannot. When I click on the Continue button it does not show the login option where I can enter my email and password. What can be the issue?

Comment: If I go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts, tap +, choose Apple ID, then click Continue, I see a prompt to enter an Apple ID. That's with Xcode 14.2.

Comment: i don't know why its not showing in mine is because of i change password of app store but it should be able to show login option